# How to respond api call and then execute code in php

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, response

I have to connect api that states:

> Our system sends events to your application, it does
>   so in a manner that it expects an immediate reply but does not wait
>   for all processing to take place. When an event is received, an
>   immediate reply is made back to our system to say the message was
>   received. The acknowledge event call follows to state that the event
>   has been processed by the third party. Our system has to
>   process millions of events daily and awaiting for the third party to
>   finish processing an event while distributing events would cause
>   unnecessary delay.

Now i am in a problem because i dont understand how can i immediately respond to their server that i have get their data if i used the return keyword in 1st line then it will not execute the code after it and in other cases they have to wait for my process to finish.

I have tried with echo 1. but it does not work.

Note: for successfull response i have to send 1 as integer to let them know that i have get their data

Comment: You're probably going to need sockets.

Comment: You can echo 1 and flush it, I think.

Comment: But I don't like their tone much. Cheeky bl**ders.

Comment: @nickb i do not have any experience on socket programming do you have any sample code for this workaround?

Comment: You can look at [the php docs examples](http://us.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php) to get a feel.

Comment: @Pete i dont understand the flush thing how can i flush the output?

Comment: @ShayanHusaini - I've put some code in an answer. Maybe it's harder than I'm bargaining for, but sockets sounds difficult to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
header('This');
header('That');
echo 1;
flush();

//all your other code....

?>
```

Comment: @ShayanHusaini Ah well. Thanks for the feedback. How do they tell you it hasn't worked? Can you put up more of the documentation? It seems odd to have some sort of _time limit_ on exchanges over http.

Comment: It worked man.... actually it was the uploading issue file wasnt properly uploaded.... thanks for your awesome help...